# Getting " expected a ; " error message in C++

Tags: c++

I am implementing Binary search tree in C++. I have written the following code but for some reason I get an error message that says:

> expected a ;

I get above message when compiling the code.

Also I am new to C++ and I would appreciate a lot if I get some help on this one.

Some context to Binary Search Tree:

> Binary search trees keep their keys in sorted order, so that lookup
>   and other operations can use the principle of binary search: when
>   looking for a key in a tree (or a place to insert a new key), they
>   traverse the tree from root to leaf, making comparisons to keys stored
>   in the nodes of the tree and deciding, on the basis of the comparison,
>   to continue searching in the left or right subtrees. On average, this
>   means that each comparison allows the operations to skip about half of
>   the tree, so that each lookup, insertion or deletion takes time
>   proportional to the logarithm of the number of items stored in the
>   tree. This is much better than the linear time required to find items
>   by key in an (unsorted) array, but slower than the corresponding
>   operations on hash tables.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;

     Node *left, *right, *parent;

};
Node* DeleteNode(Node *root, int data);

void find_min(Node *root);

void inorder(Node *x);
void Insert(Node *root, int data);

//delete a node
//search_tree
//insert a node
//temp->parent = NULL;


int main()
{
    Node *root, *temp;

    //node with 20

    temp = new Node;
    temp->data = 20;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    root = temp;

    //node with 10 

    temp = new Node;
    temp->data = 10;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->parent = NULL;

    root->left = temp;
    temp->parent = root;

    //node with 30

    temp = new Node;
    temp->data = 30;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->parent = NULL;

    root->right = temp;

    temp->parent = root;

    //node with 25

    temp = new Node;
    temp->data = 25;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->parent = NULL;

    root->right->left = temp;
    temp->parent = root->right;

    //node with 40

    temp = new Node;
    temp->data = 40;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->parent = NULL;

    root->right->right = temp;
    temp->parent = root->right;

    //node with 2

    temp = new Node;
    temp->data = 2;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->parent = NULL;

    root->left->left = temp;
    temp->parent = root->left;

    //node with 15

    temp = new Node;
    temp->data = 15;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    temp->parent = NULL;

    root->left->right = temp;

    temp->parent = root->left;

    find_min(root);
    cout << "Printing numbers in order" << endl;
    inorder(root);
    cout << "printing in-order of the given root" << endl;
    delete(root);
}

void find_min(Node *root)
{
    Node *temp;

    temp = root;

    while (temp->left != NULL)
        temp = temp->left;

    cout << "min number is  " << temp->data << endl;

}

void inorder(Node *x)
{

    if (x != NULL)
    {
        inorder(x->left);
        cout << x->data << endl;
        inorder(x->right);

    }
}
    Node* DeleteNode(Node *root, int data)
    {
        if (root->data == NULL) {

            return root;
        }
        // If the key to be deleted is smaller than the root's key,
        // then it lies in left subtree

        else if (data < root->data)
            root->left = DeleteNode(root->left, data);

        // If the key to be deleted is greater than the root's key,
        // then it lies in right subtree

        else if (data > root->data)
            root->right = DeleteNode(root->right, data);

            // case 1: No child
        else if (root->left == NULL & root->right == NULL)
                delete root;

        return root;

        //data < root->data  struct Node *temp = root;
        // case 2: one child
      if (root->left == NULL){
        Node *temp = root;
        root = root->right;
        delete temp;
        return root;
    }
    //
    else if (root->right == NULL) {
        Node *temp = root;
        root = root->left;
        delete temp;
        return root;
    }
    // case 3: two child
    else (root == root->right){
        root->data = temp->data;
        root->right = DeleteNode(root->right, temp->data);
        return root;
    }


}
```

Comment: What line is it on? You might have accidentally forgotten to type a semicolon.

Comment: `if (root->data == NULL)`  ?? data is a integer, not a pointer

Comment: Hi @FeiXiang, IDE throws error at the last else block of the program. I have put semicolons in required places. Very weird I am still getting this error message.

Comment: You put a condition in an `else` statement as pointed out by the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

This is your issue: `else (root == root->right){`.  If you want to make that a condition, you'll need to use `else if(root == root->right)`

Note that per [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/pcdnMi), you have more errors even with that fix (they look simple to fix).